# How to delete item from JSON server list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm trying to delete item from the list but, i think my endpoint is incorrect.

My enpoint is like: `http://localhost:3001/notes/360e88a6-6dde-4971-b32c-802963013c29` and id is genereated by uuid.

JSON structure is like `{ content: "seoul", phone: "111-222-333", date: "11.4.2022", important: false, id: "4426ad6e-e22f-4a83-859c-a3436bf06959" }, { content: "daegu", phone: "555-666-777", date: "11.4.2022", important: true, id: "03c08131-4866-40a3-b44c-e161c163e467" }`

Functionality

````
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/notes'
const delete_person = (id) => {
  return axios.delete(`${baseUrl}/${id}`)
}

  function handleDelete(id) {
    const newList = todos.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    axios.delete().then(response => {
      setContacts(contacts.concat(response.data))
      setNumberInput('');
      });
      return setTodos(newList);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <ol>
        {notes.map((todo, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
                <span>Name: {todo.content}, </span>
                <span>Phone {todo.phone}, </span>
                <span>Date {todo.date}, </span>
                <button type="button" onClick={handleDelete}>
                Remove
                </button>
              </li>
          )      
        })}
    </ol>```
````

Comment: Why do you think the problem is in the frontend?

Comment: Just change `onClick={handleDelete}` to `onClick={() => handleDelete(index)}` and  `axios.delete().then(` to `axios.delete(delete_person(id)).then(` and try. Make sure you have properly written the Component. I cannot see rander() method here. Try to user `handleClick(id)` as method not actually as outside function. And that would. it's better if you post your proper code with `render()` etc. but still I tried to  answer acc. to whatever I got. This may help you out https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/04/23/react-axios-http-delete-request-examples.

Comment: It works. `<button type="button" onClick={() => handleDelete(todo.id)}>` and i added id as parameter to axios call `function handleDelete(id) {     const newList = todos.filter((item) => item.id !== id);     Endpoint.delete(id).then(response => {       setContacts(contacts.concat(response.data))       setNumberInput('');       });       setTodos(newList);` This did the trick after 2 days finally